# Vector constructor memory allocation for constant iterators, seg fault

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, implementation, fault

I am having troubles figuring out how to allocate space for this constructor.  It is supposed to construct a Vector with elements from another Vector between start and end.

```
template <class T> Vector<T>::Vector(const_iterator start, const_iterator finish)
{
    array = new T[2 * capacity()];

    for( ; start != finish; start++ ){
        push_back(*start);
    }
}
```

I have been trying to debug this, but cannot figure it out.  push_back looks like so:

```
template <class T> void Vector<T>::push_back(const T & val)
{
    if (size() == capacity()) {
        reserve (2 * capacity() + 1);
    }

    array[ theSize++ ] = val;
}
```

Which calls reserve..

```
template <class T> void Vector<T>::reserve(int newCapacity)
{
    if (newCapacity < size()) {
        return;
    }

    T * array_copy = array;

    array = new T [newCapacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        array[i] = array_copy[i];
    }

    theCapacity = newCapacity;

    delete [] array_copy;
}
```

So, to narrow the question down:

Why is the segmentation fault happening?

Comment: Have you debugged it using gdb, valgrind or both?

Comment: Also, what type `T` are you instantiating the template class with and where do you get the iterators that you call the constructor with?

Comment: You didn't initialize `size()` and `capacity()` in the constructor. The `push_back()` called in constructor may be affected by the randomly initialized values.

Comment: Did you initialize the `theSize`, `theCapacity`? How exactly did it crash?

Comment: @timrau Wow, I spent so much time trying to figure out what was going on and it was that easy, haha.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize `size()` and `capacity()` in the constructor. The `push_back()` called in constructor may be affected by the randomly initialized values.